# determining if proper subsets using linked lists

Tags: c++

I am trying to determine whether two linked lists are a proper subset…

not sure how I am getting this as false, when it should be true, since P contains all elements of Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset q to the start of q each time you look through it.

For this you need to save the original node before the for loop, and reset it each time:

```
Node *q_start = q;
for(p=p; p!=NULL; p=p->next) {
    q = q_start;
```

This should be the easiest fix, but not the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you use P = {1, 2, 3} and Q = {1, 2, 3, 4}, the code you provided should return true.  However, that's only because you P is a subset of Q **and it's values occur in the same order as they do in Q**.  If you are iterating through P to check that each value is in Q, you will need to check **all** of Q - not just the remaining part you haven't checked yet.  Additionally, the code

```
if (p!=NULL && q==NULL)
    return false;
```

near the top of your function is unecessary, because you also check for q==NULL in your for loop:

```
if(q==NULL)
      return false;
```